# Capybara/Selenium - NS_ERROR_MALFORMED_URI for app on http://localhost

Tags: ruby, selenium, capybara

I'm trying to set up RSpec, Capybara & Selenium to test a PHP application running on the traditional localhost:80. Whenever I run the suite, Selenium fails and complains about a malformed URI.

Here's my spec_helper.rb.

```
require 'bundler/setup'
require 'rspec'
require 'capybara/rspec'

Capybara.server_port = 80
Capybara.app_host = 'http://localhost'
Capybara.run_server = false
Capybara.default_driver = :selenium
```

And here's my only spec:

```
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../spec_helper'

describe "visting the website", :type => :request do

  it "should display an html page" do  
      visit ( '/' )
      page.should have_selector( 'html' )
  end  

end
```

But it bails. What am I missing?

```
Failures:

  1) visting the website should display an html page
     Failure/Error: visit ( '/' )
     Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError:
       Component returned failure code: 0x804b000a (NS_ERROR_MALFORMED_URI) [nsIIOService.newURI]
     # ./spec/requests/sign_in_spec.rb:6:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

My URI doesn't look malformed to me... `visit` works if I pass in 'http://localhost' but that's not ideal.

Here's my Gemfile for good measure

```
gem 'rspec'
gem 'capybara', :git => 'https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara.git'
gem 'launchy'
gem 'ruby-debug19'
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please check stable version of Capybara. I have 1.1.2 and I can't reproduce this error. In my version capybara apply default values (see url method https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/1.1_stable/lib/capybara/server.rb#L38)

Comment: I'm using 1.1.2 and I'm having this same problem.

Comment: Agh, in my case we were using `visit "logout"` without the slash.  When I put the slash in, e.g. `visit "/logout"`, we were good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@andrykonchin was right - switching back to stable worked

Answer (score 0):

You need install bundler if it is not install

```
gem install bundler
```

Then you need to create a file called gemfile in the root directory (For my simple example I am using just capybara and no rspec)

```
source "http://rubygems.org"
gem "capybara" , "1.1.3"
```

Create a basic ruby file as follows

```
require 'bundler/setup'
require 'capybara/dsl'

Capybara.server_port = 80
Capybara.app_host = 'http://google.com'
Capybara.run_server = false
Capybara.default_driver = :selenium

class Browser
  include Capybara::DSL
end

w = Browser.new

w.visit("/")
```

Use the command

```
bundle install
```

Now you will be using the stable version of Capybara

For more information on bundler look at http://gembundler.com/